# Can we implement "DigitalClock" widget by using separate images for each number?

Tags: android

Actually I want to implement the "DigitalClock" widget by using separate images for each number.
e.g.:- For time - **01:23**, I have to use separate image for '0', '1', '2, & '3'.
Is it possible? If possible, then please provide some reference to implement it. Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem here? I don't see where using 10 different images to display a clock is problematic. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Till Helge Helwig, thanks for reply. Actually, I have to include Digital minutes inside the dial of the "AnalogClock" widget. Currently

Comment: Hi Till Helge Helwig, thanks for reply. Actually, I have to include Digital minutes inside the dial of the "AnalogClock" widget. Currently I have implemented Digital minutes with the help of textview & updating the textview with updateAppWidget(). But I want to display "Digital minutes" with separate image for each digit.

Comment: Hi Dr.nik, thanks for reply. I will use your idea, & next time I will ask a question in a more proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to do it that easily. Instead I created a layout with ImageViews and then updated them through a service running in the background (assuming you want to create a widget).